# How to know MySQL replication status using a select query?

Tags: mysql, replication, status

Is it possible to get **replication status** from any system database table?

Using which I can identify whether the replication is **up or down**.

I need to to know whether the `SLAVE_IO_RUNNING` and `SLAVE_SQL_RUNNING = YES` from a system table.

Answer (score 16):

This is the statement that I have used based on Manasi's top answer.

```
SELECT variable_value 
FROM information_schema.global_status 
WHERE variable_name='SLAVE_RUNNING';
```

Comment: Hi, as said [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/status-table.html), starting with version 5.7 `information_schema.global_status` is now deprecated.

Comment: As `information_schema.global_status` is now deprecated, referer to @bad-tea response, it talk about enable `master-info-repository` and `relay-log-info-repository` variables that enable access to this kind of information.

Answer (score 13):

[hslakhan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38614383/857626) works for MySQL 5.6, but for **MySQL 5.7** the slave status variables have moved from `information_schema` to `performance_schema`.

`Slave_IO_Running` corresponds to:

```
SELECT SERVICE_STATE FROM performance_schema.replication_connection_status;
```

`Slave_SQL_Running` corresponds to:

```
SELECT SERVICE_STATE FROM performance_schema.replication_applier_status;
```

There are some other variables from the `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` output too, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_show_compatibility_56_slave_status for the rest.

Answer (score 11):

Based on this question I've written a query to answer you.
Please maintain the copyright :-)

```
SELECT 
    channel_name AS Channel_Name,
    smi.host AS Master_Host,
    smi.user_name AS Master_User,
    smi.port AS Master_Port,
    smi.master_log_name AS Master_Log_File,
    smi.master_log_pos AS Read_Master_Log_Pos,
    ssi.master_log_pos AS Exec_Master_Log_Pos,
    rcs.service_state AS Slave_IO_Running,
    rss.service_state AS Slave_SQL_Running,
    t.processlist_time AS Seconds_Behind_Master,
    rcs.last_error_number AS Last_IO_Errno,
    rcs.last_error_message AS Last_IO_Error,
    rss.last_error_number AS Last_SQL_Errno,
    rss.last_error_message AS Last_SQL_Error,
    tc.processlist_state AS  Slave_IO_State,
    t.processlist_state AS  Slave_SQL_Running_State

FROM
    mysql.slave_master_info smi 
        JOIN
    mysql.slave_relay_log_info ssi USING (channel_name)   
        JOIN 
    performance_schema.replication_connection_status rcs USING (channel_name)
        LEFT JOIN
    performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker rss USING (channel_name)
        LEFT JOIN
    performance_schema.threads t ON (rss.thread_id = t.thread_id)
        LEFT JOIN
    performance_schema.threads tc ON (rcs.thread_id = tc.thread_id)
\G
```

Best regards, 
Renan Benedicto Pereira (BR MySQL DBA)

**Note:** This wont work unless `master_info_repository = TABLE` and `relay_log_info_repository=TABLE` is enabled, FILE option is the default, will not work

Comment: The column "processlist_time" from performance_schema.threads for the connection thread is not the same value as "Seconds_Behind_Master". This info is wrong.

Comment: The [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-threads-table.html) for MySQL 5.6, 5.7, and 8.0 seem to indicate it should be equivalent: 

"For a replica SQL thread, the value is the number of seconds between the timestamp of the last replicated event and the real time of the replica host. See Section 16.2.3, “[Replication Threads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-implementation-details.html)”. Am I missing something?

Comment: "Please maintain the copyright :-)" - is that a genuine request for attribution, or are you just noting that the necessary query is so complex that it perhaps constitutes an original work?  (Or both?)

Answer (score 5):

This solution uses **awk** to process a show command output and sends a mail in case of errors in any of the field processed. In this case the fields are *Slave_IO_Running* and *Slave_SQL_Running*. 
 Fill free to add other fields from the 'show slave status' output - *Last_Error/Seconds_Behind_Master* for example or to **awk** the output of other show commands.

```
#!/bin/bash  
# get some slave stats  
Slave_IO_Running=`mysql -u root --password="pwd" -Bse "show slave status\G" | grep Slave_IO_Running | awk '{ print $2 }'`  
Slave_SQL_Running=`mysql -u root --password="pwd" -Bse "show slave status\G" | grep Slave_SQL_Running | awk '{ print $2 }'`  
Last_error=`mysql -u root --password="pwd" -Bse "show slave status\G" | grep Last_error | awk -F : '{ print $2 }'`  

if [ $Slave_SQL_Running == 'No' ] || [ $Slave_IO_Running == 'No' ];  
then  
    echo "Last Error:" $Last_error | mail -s "Replication error on slavedb!!!" devops@company.com  
fi  

exit 0
```

Comment: pls describe your solution

Comment: as requested, pls see above

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Improvement proposal: Fetch the status only once and do the rest locally.
Also, I suggest to use "grep -i" for case insensitive grep. On my server running mysql 5.6 "Last_Error" has uppercase E.

Comment: let people learn using 
man {cmd_name}
give them code with some errors so that they have to understand it before just pasting it ;)

Comment: This answer doesn't address the original question, which was how to get the information from a system table (e.g. via SELECT statement).

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution in information_schema database. Please check the table GLOBAL_STATUS in information_schema database. You will see a variable "SLAVE_RUNNING" if it is "ON" that means replication is working fine. If it is "OFF" then replication has failed due to any reason and you need to check why? :-)

Manasi

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there a select query that can yield this information?

I did a lot of searching for this answer, I really hate scrolling after running `show slave status;`.

I like @renan's answer. This answer focuses on `show slave status;`, the `common_schema`, and alternatives if that isn't available.

#### Easy, but not customizable (and not `SELECT`):

`show slave status;`

---

#### If you have access to `common_schema` and primarily want seconds behind master:

```
SELECT SECONDS_BEHIND_MASTER, 
       slave_status.* 
FROM common_schema.slave_status;
```

---

#### If you only want the last error message, ignoring seconds behind master:

```
SELECT LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE,
       LAST_ERROR_TIMESTAMP,
       replication_applier_status_by_worker.*
FROM performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker
```

---

#### What I use (both):

This shows the most recent error on the same row as the `SECONDS_BEHIND_MASTER`. If this value is non-zero, it's possible there is a large query running, or there's an error that you would find in the `show slave status;` command, or you could find it in the `performance_schema`.

```
SELECT LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE,
       LAST_ERROR_TIMESTAMP,
       SECONDS_BEHIND_TABLE.*
FROM performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker
         left join (select SECONDS_BEHIND_MASTER,
                           null                 'RUNNING_INDICATORS ->',
                           SLAVE_RUNNING,
                           SLAVE_IO_RUNNING,
                           SLAVE_SQL_RUNNING,
                           'show slave status;' FOR_MORE
                    from common_schema.slave_status) SECONDS_BEHIND_TABLE on TRUE;
```

---

#### Last: if you don't have access to `common_schema` but wish you did:

**Please note:** this is exclusively the work of [Shlomi Noach](https://github.com/shlomi-noach), from his [open source library](https://github.com/shlomi-noach/common_schema), which I have molded into a single query. This should be identical to the output of `SELECT * FROM common_schema.slave_status;`

```
SELECT SUM(IF(is_io_thread, TIME, NULL))                                      AS Slave_Connected_time,
       SUM(is_io_thread) IS TRUE                                              AS Slave_IO_Running,
       SUM(is_sql_thread OR (is_system AND NOT is_io_thread)) IS TRUE         AS Slave_SQL_Running,
       (SUM(is_system) = 2) IS TRUE                                           AS Slave_Running,
       SUM(IF(is_sql_thread OR (is_system AND NOT is_io_thread), TIME, NULL)) AS Seconds_Behind_Master
FROM (
         SELECT PROCESSLIST.*,
                USER = 'system user'                                                     AS is_system,
                (USER = 'system user' AND state_type = 'replication_io_thread') IS TRUE  AS is_io_thread,
                (USER = 'system user' AND state_type = 'replication_sql_thread') IS TRUE AS is_sql_thread,
                COMMAND = 'Binlog Dump'                                                  AS is_slave
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST
                  LEFT JOIN (
             -- Replication SQL thread states
             select 'Waiting for the next event in relay log' state, 'replication_sql_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Reading event from the relay log' state, 'replication_sql_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Making temp file' state, 'replication_sql_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it' state, 'replication_sql_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Waiting until MASTER_DELAY seconds after master executed event' state, 'replication_sql_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it' state, 'replication_sql_thread' state_type
             union
             -- Replication I/O thread states
             select 'Waiting for an event from Coordinator' state, 'replication_io_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Waiting for master update' state, 'replication_io_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Connecting to master ' state, 'replication_io_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Checking master version' state, 'replication_io_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Registering slave on master' state, 'replication_io_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Requesting binlog dump' state, 'replication_io_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Waiting to reconnect after a failed binlog dump request' state, 'replication_io_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Reconnecting after a failed binlog dump request' state, 'replication_io_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Waiting for master to send event' state, 'replication_io_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Queueing master event to the relay log' state, 'replication_io_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Waiting to reconnect after a failed master event read' state, 'replication_io_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Reconnecting after a failed master event read' state, 'replication_io_thread' state_type
             union
             select 'Waiting for the slave SQL thread to free enough relay log space' state, 'replication_io_thread' state_type
         ) known_states ON (known_states.state LIKE CONCAT(PROCESSLIST.STATE, '%'))
         WHERE USER = 'system user'
            OR COMMAND = 'Binlog Dump'
     ) common_schema_slave_status;
```

---

**Sources:**

- A lot of googling, where I finally found this awesome doc on [`common_schema.slave_status`](https://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/slave_status.html)
- Whose project is open source, and accessible [here](https://github.com/shlomi-noach/common_schema), where I mainly used the definition of [_known_thread_states](https://github.com/shlomi-noach/common_schema/blob/master/tables/_known_thread_states.sql), which is a table in the library, to recompose what those of us with access to his work can make use of in `common_schema.slave_status`, which is a view in the library.
- The docs on the [performance schema replication tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-replication-tables.html). (I queried all tables in `performance_schema.replication_*` until I found [one](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-replication-applier-status-by-worker-table.html) that showed the specific error I was looking for, which you can see at the above link, just scroll down a while.)

Best, Spencer

Answer (score 2):

The primary statement for this is SHOW SLAVE STATUS, which you must execute on each slave.
Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-administration-status.html

On the master, you can check the status of connected slaves using SHOW PROCESSLIST to examine the list of running processes.
For slaves that were started with the --report-host option and are connected to the master, the SHOW SLAVE HOSTS statement on the master shows basic information about the slaves.

Answer (score 2):

Beginning in MySQL 5.6, you can store the slave status in tables rather than files by starting the server with `--master-info-repository=TABLE` and `--relay-log-info-repository=TABLE`.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slave-logs.html

Even with that, I'm not sure if the tables will contain the specific values you are looking for (`SLAVE_IO_RUNNING` and `SLAVE_SQL_RUNNING`).  I could not try this because I'm running mysql 5.1; I was just searching and found it in the 5.6 documentation.

It sounds like you are trying to monitor the thread status in an automated fashion.  Since I do not have the tables, I plan to do this with a shell script and cron job, with something like this:

```
$ mysql -u root -pXXXX -e "SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G" | grep Slave_IO_Running | awk '{ print $2 }'
$ mysql -u root -pXXXX -e "SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G" | grep Slave_SQL_Running | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Reference: http://www.stardothosting.com/blog/2012/02/checking-and-repairing-mysql-replication-automatically/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the fuss is about tbh. 'show slave status' IS a query. You can execute that query from any modern programming language and then simply choose the column names you wish to use right?

In PHP for example I use:

```
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    print "Slave_IO_Running: " . $row['Slave_IO_Running'] . "\n";
```

After getting the results from 'show slave status' in $row.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run this at master.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST AS p WHERE p.COMMAND = 'Binlog Dump';
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5.7 we get this info as follows:

```sql
select
    ras.SERVICE_STATE as sql_status,
    rcs.SERVICE_STATE as io_status,
    t.PROCESSLIST_TIME as slave_lag
from
    performance_schema.replication_applier_status ras
join replication_connection_status rcs
left join performance_schema.threads t on
    t.NAME = 'thread/sql/slave_sql'
left join information_schema.processlist pl on
    pl.id = t.PROCESSLIST_ID;
```

Answer (score -3):

afaik, there is no select (like information_schema)

to check slave replication status

```
show slave status;
```

reference -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-slave-status.html