# How to check Slave_IO_Running, Slave_SQL_Running, Seconds_Behind_Master from SHOW SLAVE STATUS on MASTER

Tags: mysql, master-slave

I'm looking for a way to fetch following information from [SHOW SLAVE SATUS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-slave-status.html) on MASTER server in MySQL 5.6:

- `Slave_IO_Running`
- `Slave_SQL_Running`
- `Seconds_Behind_Master`

SHOW SLAVE SATUS shows me info only on replica/slave server, where read-only mode is my only possibility, which makes writing procedure unavailable for me.

I found this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009021/how-to-know-mysql-replication-status-using-a-select-query/58096132#58096132) somewhat usefull, unfortunetly relates on querying slave server, which is not my target and are usefull mostly for MySQL above 5.6.

Comment: you can try `SELECT variable_name, variable_value 
FROM information_schema.global_status;`

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA yup, I have tried it before  - shows SLAVE_RUNNING only when Slave is queried, not Master, and I'm not sure this corresponds to variables I'm looking for.

Comment: few of slave info by default keeps in master info file. So you can fetch like this on bash `mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -e "show slave status\G" | egrep '(Seconds_Behind_Master|Slave_IO_Running|Slave_SQL_Running)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slave keeps info by default in Master info file. So you can fetch like this on bash:

```
> mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -e "show slave status\G" | egrep
> '(Seconds_Behind_Master|Slave_IO_Running|Slave_SQL_Running)'
```